# Bash prompt variables does not work inside a bash function

Tags: linux, bash, prompt

I'm working on a prompt customization, but for some reason, when I use the `\u`, `\h` and `\W` variables as is it works perfectly, but when I put them inside a function, they are displayed as "\u" or "\W" instead of their values.

```sh
...

print_user()
{
  echo -e "\001\u\002@\001\h\002"
}

print_dir()
{
  echo -e "\001${YELLOW}\002\001\W\002\001${RESET_ATTR}\002"
}

PS1='[$(print_user) on $(print_dir)] $(get_git_repo) \001\n\002$(print_prompt) '
```

This displays as:

```
[\u@\h on \W]
>
```

If I move them outside of the function like so

```sh
PS1='[\[\u\]@\[\h\] \[${YELLOW}\]\[\w\]\[${RESET_ATTR}\]] $(get_git_repo) \[\n\]$(print_prompt)'
```

It works fine, and displays the current directory with the username and hostname:

```
[myusername@arch on ~]
>
```

Is this just how bash works? Is there a different way of doing it so it will work? Why is it that inside of a function it won't display the variables' values but outside of a function it does?

Comment: My guess is that command substitutions are evaluated after the prompt escapes, so by the time `print_user` produces its output, it's too late to replace `\u` with the current user's name.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That's intentional, so that the command substation is evaluated each time the prompt is displayed, rather than when the prompt string is defined.

Comment: @chepner 'doh, you're right! Today is my not-very-shmart-day.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, that might be the case and it just has to be outside of a function. It will making the script a bit uglier but that's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page, under `PROMPTING`

> Bash allows these prompt strings to be customized by  inserting  a  number  of
> backslash-escaped special characters that are decoded as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> **After** the string is decoded, it is expanded via parameter expansion, **command substitution**, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal,  subject  to  the  value  of  the
> promptvars shell option (see the description of the shopt command under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

By the time the shell expands `$(print_user)` to add `\u` to the string, it is too late to decode it, so the literal string `\u` remains in the prompt.

One alternative is to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to execute a function that defines `PS1` dynamically, just before it is displayed, instead of embedding command substitution in the value of `PS1` itself.

```
make_prompt () {
  PS1="[$(print_user) on $(print_dir)] $(get_git_repo)"
  PS1+='\[\n\]'
  PS1+="$(print_prompt) "
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=make_prompt
```

Now, `print_user` will have been called *before* the shell decodes the value of `PS1`, by which time all the prompt escapes will be present.

Comment: Yes that does sounds like the case. Thanks a lot!